# Laravel ordering results by specific values

Tags: mysql, laravel, sql-order-by, eloquent

I have this line of code which gets results from a database:

```
'clanMembers' => User::find(Auth::user() -> clan_id) -> where('clan_id', '=', Auth::user() -> clan_id) -> orderBy('username') -> get()
```

Currently it orders by the username. I wish to change this to order by the clan_rank field. This clan_rank field will only ever contain 3 different values. These are:

```
1. Owner
2. Admin
3. Member
```

I wish to have my results ordered with Owners first, then Admin, then members. How can I change my line of code to achieve these results?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need to use `orderByRaw`:

instead of `orderBy` part you should use

```
orderByRaw("FIELD(clan_rank , 'Owner', 'Admin', 'Member') ASC");
```

Comment: Now what if 'Owner', 'Admin', and 'Member' are stored as a user-configurable array value in the database that you are retrieving results from (not hard-coded)? In my use case I have a 'clan_rank_order' column JSON property type field in my MySQL database where the user's order by sort priority is stored.